# jQuery: how to use :checked, if my element is $(this)

Tags: jquery

how can I use the option :checked with $(this) in jQuery ?

i.e. $(this:checked) ?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(this).filter(":checked");
```

or if you're testing it

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Unless you're doing something _really_ weird, `this` will only be one element.

Comment: @Slaks - Yes, but that seems to be what the original intent of the question was.  Plus, you can do something like `$(this).filter(":checked").addClass("checked")` to only add the class if the element is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use is() method.

`$(this).is(':checked')` returns boolean.

Answer (score 1):

The checkbox Node has its own property `checked`, so:

```
if (this.checked) ...
```

there is no need to make jQuery do a bunch of work by packaging that trivially simple check in a selector. The DOM version is perfectly readable.

Answer (score 0):

try it `$(':checked', $(this))`

Comment: That looks for checked input *inside* `this`.